# How to get backBarButtonItem center?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uinavigationbar, cgpoint

if i use this code:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.center()
```

returns Nil, if i get all the navigation bar itens, it says that have no buttons.

(I want to get the button center to show a little tutorial to user)

Comment: Did you actually set the backBarButtonItem property? Per default it is nil and the navigation bar will show the standard back button which uses the titel of the presenting view controller as button text.

Comment: Actually i want to get the default back button center

Comment: Yes, you said that already. It just does not work this way unless you provide your own custom `backBarButtonItem`.